# symfony2 semantic bundle configuration - conditional required parameter

Tags: symfony, configuration, dependency-injection

I am working on a bundle that have a couple of required parameters. I want to be able to disable the bundle by setting `enabled: false` in my parameters.yml.
If the bundle is disabled the configuration parameters cant be required any more.

Is there anyway I can say in bundle configuration class that the required parameters are only required if the enabled parameter is true?

Thank you.

EDIT:

My Configuration.php

```
 $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('settings')
                    ->canBeEnabled()
                    ->children()
                        ->scalarNode('api_key')
                            ->isRequired()
                            ->cannotBeEmpty()
                        ->end()
                        ->scalarNode('api_secret')
                            ->isRequired()
                            ->cannotBeEmpty()
                        ->end()
                        ->booleanNode('debug')
                            ->defaultFalse()
                            ->cannotBeEmpty()
                        ->end()
                        ->booleanNode('ssl')
                            ->defaultFalse()
                        ->end()
                    ->end()
            ->end();
```

If i set this in parameters.yml,

```
my_bundle:
  settings:
    enabled: false
```

It shouldnt complain about `"The child node "api_key" at path "my_bundle.settings" must be configured."`

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html#optional-sections

Comment: If you want to turn off the bundle may be better to remove it from the AppKernel.php?

Comment: I have tought of it but there is a service that I need to use from that bundle so i cant disable it. I cant move the service from the bundle. Well i can put dummy data in the required fields but that is not really elegant. Symfony should provide a way to say that a parameter is only required if other parameter has a certain value. Maybe i Will open a feature request if this is not possible

Comment: @brpaz I'm stuck at exactly the same point as you, did you find a solution in the mean time?